# Выровнять блок по центру

Tags: html, css

```css
#cont {
        position: relative;
        background: red;
        height: 500px;
        width: 500px;
    }
    #ms {
        font-size:20px;
        position: absolute;
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

```html
<div id=cont>
        <div id=ms>
            ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст<br>
            ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст<br>
            ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст<br>
            ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст<br>
        </div>
</div>
```

Блок по центру, но если высота габариты его будут меньше содержимого, получится слудующее

```css
#cont {
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
#ms {
    font-size:20px;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id=cont>
        <div id=ms>
            ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст<br>
            ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст<br>
            ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст<br>
            ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст<br>
        </div>
</div>
```

Вопрос в том, как выровнять дочерний блок по центру и сделать так, чтобы ширина и высота родителя не были меньше дочернего.

Главное, содержимое родиеля может быть любым, может это список статей, выравнивать его по центру не нужно, возможно статей нету и необходимо выровнять дочерний блок.

То есть возможно ли выровнять дочерний блок, присвоить какие либо свойства но при этом не трогать родителя.

Другими словами, сделать дочерний блок блочным и выставить его по центру

Comment: Это за-за слитного текста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### 1. Центрирование

Родителя изменить всё равно придётся, иначе трудно добиться нужного результата. Для грамотного позиционирования блоков, как верно [отметил @SonOfAMother](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1432570/485503), хорош `flex`:

```css
.cont {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.ms {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="ms">
ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст<br />
ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст<br />
ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст<br />
ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст<br />
  </div>
</div>
```

`flex` - полезнейший инструмент. Советую его как следует изучить:

- [Документация](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
- [Шпаргалка](https://tpverstak.ru/flex-cheatsheet/)
- [Песочница](http://flexbox.help/)
- [Для освоения](https://flexboxfroggy.com/#ru)

##### 2. Переполнение контента

В данном случае оно возникает из-за жёстко заданных размеров родителя. Если эта жёсткость так необходима, то можно воспользоваться свойством `overflow`.

Он принимает несколько значений. Подробнее о них [здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/css/overflow). Я рекомендую в данной ситуации `auto`:

```css
.cont {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.ms {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="ms">
ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст<br />
ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст<br />
ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст<br />
ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст<br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Если ни одно из свойств `overflow` вам не подходит, то придётся отказаться от жёстко заданных размеров. Но, как правило, этого вполне хватает.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете решить вопрос с размерами и выравниванием если будете использовать flex или grid контейнеры. Они позволяют подстраивать содержимое под размеры контейнера и наоборот, а также очень просто выравнивать содержимое. Если вы хотите создать адаптивный дизайн, который бы показывался одинаково правильно при любых размерах, то вам обязательно следует познакомиться с вышеуказанными flex и grid, вот хорошие статьи на эти темы ([Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout), [Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)).

Кроме того, следует отказаться от использования абсолютных величин по типу px (пиксели), pt (кегли) и т.п., лучше использовать относительные по типу % (процент от родительской величины), em (множитель стандартного размера шрифта) и т.п.

Это общие рекомендации, при необходимости могу сделать пример конкретно для вашего документа.